# Manipulate row values based on lists

Tags: python

i have actually a problem and I do not know how to solve it.

I have two lists, which have always the same lengths:

```
max_values = [333,30,10]
min_values = [30,10,0]
```

every index of the lists represents the cluster number of a range of the max and the min values, so:

```
Index/Cluster 0: 0-10
Index/Cluster 1: 10-30
Index/Cluster 2: 30-333
```

Furthermore I have one dataframe as follows:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN76g.png)

Within the df, I have a column called "AVG_MPH_AREA"
It should be checked between which cluster range the value is. After the "Cluster" column should be set to the correct index of the list. The old values should be dropped.

In this case it's a list of 3 clusters, but it could also be more or less...

Any idea how to switch that or with which functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a small function that could do the task

```
max_values = [333,30,10]
min_values = [30,10,0]
```

Make a dictionary that contains `Cluster_num` as key and `(min_values, max_values)` as value.

```
def temp_func(x):
 
 # constructing the dict inside to apply this func to AVG_MPH_AREA column in dataframe
  dt = {}
  cluster_list=list(zip(min_values, max_values))
  for i in range(len(cluster_list)):
    dt[i] = cluster_list[i]
  for key, value in dt.items():
    x = int(round(x))
    if x in list(range(value[0], value[1])):
       return key
    else:
       continue
```

Now apply the function to the `AVG_MPH_AREA` column

```
 df["Cluster"] = df["AVG_MPH_AREA"].apply(temp_func)

  Output:

      AVG_MPH_AREA  cluster
  0      10.770      1
  1      10.770      1
  2      10.780      1
  3      5.780       2
  4      24.960      1
  5      267.865     0
```